# Rails 4: NoMethodError undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord

In our Rails 4 app, there are three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end
```

Here are the corresponding migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :total_calendar_count
      t.integer :owned_calendar_count

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateAdministrations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :administrations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :calendar, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.string :role

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :calendars do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is how we structured our routes:

```
concern :administratable do
  resources :administrations
end

resources :users, concerns: :administratable
resources :calendars, concerns: :administratable

get 'dashboard' => 'administrations#index'
```

In the `/dashboard`, we would like users to:

- See a list of all their calendars at a glance
- Delete any of their own calendars
- Quit a calendar (ie: destroy the corresponding adminstration)

In order to achieve this, we have created the following `_administration.html.erb` partial:

```
<tr class="calendar_menu">
  <td class="administration-<%= administration.id %>">
    <span class="name"><%= link_to administration.calendar, administration.calendar %></span>
  </td>
  <td class="administration-<%= administration.id %>">
    <span class="role"><%= administration %></span>
  </td>

  <td class="administration-<%= administration.id %>">
    <span class="delete_calendar"><%= link_to 'Delete', administration.calendar, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %> </span>
  </td>

  <td class="administration-<%= administration.id %>">
    <span class="quit_calendar"><%= link_to "Quit", administration, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %> </span>
  </td>

</tr>
```

Everything worked perfectly, until we added the last `<td></td>` to allow users to quit a calendar, which resulted in the following error:

```
NoMethodError in AdministrationsController#index

undefined method `administration_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe6961596e8>:0x007fe6913714a8>

def handle_model_call(target, model)
  method, args = handle_model model
  target.send(method, *args)
end

def handle_list(list)
```

Here is what the `AdministrationsController` looked liked at this point:

```
class AdministrationsController < ApplicationController

  def to_s
    role
  end

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @administrations = @user.administrations
    @calendar = Calendar.new
  end

  def show
    @administration = Administration.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    Administration.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "You successfully quitted this calendar"
    redirect_to dashboard_path
  end

end
```

Based on the error, we modified it as follows:

```
class AdministrationsController < ApplicationController

  def to_s
    role
  end

  def index
    @user = current_user
    @administrations = @user.administrations
    @calendar = Calendar.new
    @administration = Administration.find(params[:id])
  end

  def show
    @administration = Administration.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    Administration.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "You successfully quitted this calendar"
    redirect_to dashboard_path
  end

end
```

But then, we got a new error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AdministrationsController#index

Couldn't find Administration with 'id'=

record = s.execute([id], self, connection).first
  unless record
  raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{name} with '#{primary_key}'=#{id}"
  end
  record
rescue RangeError
```

Then, we hit a wall: any idea of what we are doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried `@administrations = @user.administration` instead of the "s" at the end of `administration`

Comment: You are showing 2 errors. How did you fix `undefined method 'administration_path'`? Aren't you using nested routes, so your link should be `link_to "Quit", [administration.calendar, administration] ....`

Comment: @Cyzanfar No, we did not try this, because we actually need the `@administrations = @user.administrations` part to display the list of administrations of the user in the first place.

Comment: @AbM As explained in the questions, we "fixed" it (ie: made it disappear by causing a new error) by adding `@administration = Administration.find(params[:id])` to `AdministrationsController`, which cause the second error. The code you suggest, `link_to "Quit", [administration.calendar, administration]` works perfectly. We did not know we had to "loop" twice through `administration` to get the expected result. All the more since the `administration_path` was working in `<td class="administration-<%= administration.id %>"><span class="role"><%= administration %></span></td>`